# How does processes find shared libraries in folders under /usr/lib

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

Assume that a program needs a shared library(bar.so) under the folder /usr/lib/foo. I understand if the bar.so was directly under /usr/lib, it would be automatically found. But as in my case the library could not be found automatically, because -I think so- it is under the folder /usr/lib/foo. However there are tons of other folders under /usr/lib and the corresponding programs using those libraries are working seamlessly.

So, how does this process work and how can I fix my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a better source: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual programs can control where they search for their libraries.

Also the search path can be controlled using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Try appending /usr/lib/foo to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var.